# why a better performance (silhouette score) in python 2.7 than 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cluster-analysis

I read a lot on SoF about the difference in speed between Python 2.7 and 3.6. but my question is more about performance between the two versions.

I used for document clustering: TF-IDF + KMeans and score silhouette to evaluate the homogeneity of my clusters.

**By switching from Python 3.6 to Python 2.7, my silhouette score has increased by *+0.20!***

**Would someone have an explanation? ** Thanks!

code :

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
    stop_words=my_stopwords_str, 
    max_df=0.95, 
    min_df=5, 
    token_pattern=r'\w{3,}',
    max_features=20)

tfidf.fit(data_final.all_text)
data_vect = tfidf.transform(data_final.all_text)

num_clusters = 15

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++', 
max_iter=300).fit(data_vect_lsa)
kmeans_predict = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++', max_iter=300).fit_predict(data_vect_lsa)


silhouette_score(data_vect, labels = kmeans_predict, metric='euclidean')
```

The output for Python 2.7 is :

```
0.58234789374593758
```

The output for Python 3.6 is :

```
0.37524101598378656
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer this without more details (preferably including code).

Comment: thanks for your advice, I edit my post !

Comment: What library does `TfidfVectorizer` and `KMeans` come from? In general, something to look for might be divisions -- the behavior of the division operator `/` with integers changed from floor to true division in Python3, and if there's a hidden division with two integers somewhere in your code, that might explain the numerical discrepancy

Comment: Likely, it is an issue that depends on the *libraries* you are using. What versions? Another thing, try to se the random-seed explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try again. A single sample is not enough.

K-means begins with a random setting, and may find a local optimum only.

It's fairly common to see different results when running it multiple times.

Comment: in particular, random seeds might be different across different versions.

Comment: Well, right now the seed is not fixed at all, so every run could be different. But of course version differences can also change random values generated.